# Find by regex and replace match to lowercase in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I would like to replace all contents of a file that match a given regex to their lowercase equivalent. Like:

```
grep -o '[^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*.png' file-21-05-2013.sql* | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
```

The line above finds all strings in the given file that have at least one uppercase character and prints the lowercase equivalent.

I would like to replace the output of the grep command with the output of the whole command above

Does that make sense?

Comment: Its not a bunch files. Its the contents in a file that I need to replace.

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help you if you provided a sample of the data.

Comment: It seems easier to simply do `tr A-Z a-z`, which I believe provides what you want when you say "output of the whole command".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a GNU system then GNU sed has the following extension:

```
\L
Turn the replacement to lowercase until a \U or \E is found,
```

The following command should do what you need:

```
sed  "s/\([^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*.png\)/\L\1/g" file-21-05-2013.sql*
```

Comment: And if you add -i as an option it will do the changes directly in your file instead of printing them to stdout.

Comment: Close. But not quite. Check out this output: 

`Yannis-MacBook:Downloads yannis$ cat output-21-05-2013.sql 
<img src="testTest.png"/>
Yannis-MacBook:Downloads yannis$ sed  "s/\([^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*.png\)/\L\1/g" output-21-05-2013.sql 
<img Lsrc="testTest.png"/>`

Comment: Given your hostname you probably don't have GNU sed :-/

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -nr '/^.*\b(\w*[A-Z]\w*\.png).*$/{s//\1/;s/.*/\L\0/;p}' file
```