# Why these simple shell commands fail when used in sed's replacement part

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sed, awk

While trying to find an answer of **[this sed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669823/find-by-regex-and-replace-match-to-lowercase-in-bash)** I came up with a strange behavior that I couldn't understand.

Let's say I have a file called `data`

```
$> cat data
foo.png
abCd.png
bar.png
baZ.png
```

The task is to use sed in line to replace all the lines with uppercase ASCII characters to lowercase. So the output should be:

```
$> cat data
foo.png
abcd.png
bar.png
baz.png
```

**The solution should work on non-gnu sed also like sed on Mac**

I attempted this embedded awk into sed's replacement part:

```
sed -E 's/[^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*.png/'$(echo \&|awk '{printf("<%s>[%s]",$0, tolower($0))}')'/' data
```

Strangely this outputs this:

```
foo.png
<abCd.png>[abCd.png]
bar.png
<baZ.png>[baZ.png]
```

As you can see sed is picking up right lines with uppercase alphabets, and that's reaching to awk also but `tolower()` function of awk is failing and producing same text as input.

Can a shell expert please explain this weird behavior.

Comment: I don't have experience of mac os. also i don't have bsd sed. can you test if this works with your data? `sed 's/./\l&/g'`

Comment: when I turn on `set -vx` and execute your code (I had to remove `-E` for my `GNU sed version 4.1.5` to work, I see `sed 's/[^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*.png/<&>[&]/'` , which seems like it is the source of your problem. Sorry don't have time to explore for a fix. Good luck.

Comment: @Kent: `\l` doesn't work on sed on my Mac OS.

Comment: Pretty sure mac/bsd sed doesn't have any way to do upper->lower automatically, so you'll need another tool unless you want to build an ugly command line (`sed -e s/A/a/g -e s/B/b/g ...`)

Comment: How about an `awk` inline solution? `awk '{print tolower($0) >FILENAME}' test.in`

Comment: @Kevin: I was actually looking for sed solution. But if you post that awk as an answer I will definitely upvote it and if I cannot get any sed solution I may accept it too eventually :)

Comment: doesn't your sed support the "transliterate" cmd, ie `echo abCd.png| sed 'y/ABCD/abcd'` ? Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: Your sed outputs this: `sed: 1: "y/ABCD/abcd": unterminated transform target string`

Comment: @Kevin - you're asking for nasal demons by trying to write to the same file that you're reading. Anything could happen... If you want to do anything remotely like this in awk, you need to buffer the output in a string or array and then in the END section you close() the input file and then print to it. It usually makes more sense to just print to a tmp output file and then mv it to the original.

Comment: @anubhava wrt "The solution should work on non-gnu sed also like sed on Mac" - that is not possible since non-gnu seds don't support "inplace editing". What is it you're really trying to accomplish and which tool(s) are acceptable for a solution?

Comment: @EdMorton sed on my Mac OSX 10.6.8 does support inline editing flag `-i`

Comment: Then maybe that is GNU sed. Why say at all that it must work in non-GNU seds if you're happy with the solution provided by GNU sed? You said it must work in "non-GNU seds LIKE Mac", not that it must work in "Mac sed" so it sounded like you were looking for a general solution.

Comment: @EdMorton: I already know about `\l` solution in the linked question and that is not supported on my sed OSX 10.6.8. I don't care whether it is gnu or non-gnu sed on my mac.

Comment: sorry!  try `echo abCd.png| sed 'y/ABCD/abcd/'`... Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: Yes that works and I posted an answer utilizing `sed 'y'` command.

Comment: @anubhava - so it's just `\l` you're trying to avoid??? Wish you'd just said that in your question! I assumed it was `-i`!

Comment: @EdMorton: Its not that I am trying to avoid `\l` I am just trying to find a workable sed inline editing command that works on OSX. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in drafting my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSYUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'
```

Comment: @anubhava you said in your question that the solution has to do the subsitution inline. This solution doesn't do that. Is that OK? If so, which of your other requirements is it also OK to ignore?

Comment: Ed is right. This works will all versions of sed. However - it makes EVERY character lowercase - it does not match just a filename. If you need to do this for PART of a line, then either GNU sed is needed,or you have to use a complex sed script that splits one line into smaller lines, and then join them back.

Comment: @EdMorton: Above command can be made inline easily: `sed -i.bak 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/' data`

Comment: Bruce - I know, my point is just that we can't tell from the OPs question and subsequent comments what it is he really wants since he's happy with various things that don't solve his posted criteria.

Answer (score 10):

Your `awk` command runs before the `sed` command, not as a subprocess of the `sed` command, so `awk` is only receiving a literal ampersand as its input, as a result of which it outputs

```
<&>[&]
```

This string is then embedded in the string which `sed` receives as its argument, from which it should be fairly obvious why `sed` produces the output that it does.

The sequence of events is

1. The shell sees this command line

   ```
   sed -E 's/[^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*.png/'$(echo \&|awk '{printf("<%s>[%s]",$0, tolower($0))}')'/' data
   ```
2. It processes the command substitution (in which `awk` turns `&` into `<&>[&]`), to produce the intermediate command line

   ```
   sed -E 's/[^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*.png/'<&>[&]'/' data
   ```
3. The shell then executes `sed` with the command `s/[^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*.png/<&>[&]/`

Comment: I wasn't aware of the substitution priority, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Actually it doesn't output literal `<&>[&]` for me. I have shown output of my sed command in my question.

Comment: I get lines like this in output: `<abCd.png>[abCd.png]`

Comment: `awk` outputs a literal `<&>[&]`, but then that is incorporated into the `sed` command, and `sed` replaces each `&` with the matching text in *its* output.

Comment: @anubhava: From the sed manpage: "An ampersand (\`\`&'') appearing in the replacement is replaced by the string matching the RE.  The special meaning of ``&'' in this context can be suppressed by preceding it by a backslash."

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Thanks but then how else to use embedded shell command in sed replacement? Is it even possible?

Comment: @anubhava: It's not possible; sed doesn't have any commands that tell it to launch another command. I suppose you could have sed output a series of e.g. awk commands and then execute the output by piping it to bash, but that would be beyond ugly (and quite fragile due to shell metacharacters etc).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps `tr` is what you're really looking for?

```
tr A-Z a-z file
```

The `sed` equivalent would be:

```
sed -e 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'
```

It doesn't appear that you can use the character range notation (`A-Z` and/or `[A-Z]`), which is unfortunate and annoying.

Comment: I know about tr, requirement is this: `Task is to use sed inline`

Comment: @chepner: It isn't my requirement, it is the requirement of the linked question that I waas trying to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm 99% sure you can't do this directly on Mac/BSD `sed` without something particularly ugly (`sed -e s/A/a/g -e s/B/b/g ...`), so until and unless a `sed` solution is found, here's an `awk` one that does it inline:

```
awk '{print tolower($0) >FILENAME}' data
```

Comment: I know about tr, requirement is this: `Task is to use sed inline`

Comment: @Kevin - you're asking for nasal demons by trying to write to the same file that you're reading. Anything could happen... If you want to do anything remotely like this in awk, you need to buffer the output in a string or array and then in the END section you close() the input file and then print to it. It usually makes more sense to just print to a tmp output file and then mv it to the original.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to convert to lowercase in plain `sed`, it's possible but rather ugly:

```
sed -e s/A/a/g -e s/B/b/g -e s/C/c/g -e s/D/d/g -e s/E/e/g -e s/F/f/g -e s/G/g/g -e s/H/h/g -e s/I/i/g -e s/J/j/g -e s/K/k/g -e s/L/l/g -e s/M/m/g -e s/N/n/g -e s/O/o/g -e s/P/p/g -e s/Q/q/g -e s/R/r/g -e s/S/s/g -e s/T/t/g -e s/U/u/g -e s/V/v/g -e s/W/w/g -e s/X/x/g -e s/Y/y/g -e s/Z/z/g
```

EDIT: Never mind, @Bruce Barnett's solution is better

Answer (score 2):

Are you really sure you cannot use Perl?

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/([^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*\.png)/\l\1/' file
```

That's backslash-ell to specify lowercase, backslash-one to repeat the first matching group.

Comment: +1 Was looking for `use sed inline` but Perl is definitely a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some *good* answers here is a **workaround solution** I could come up with:

```
sed -i.bak 'y/'$(awk 'BEGIN {for(i=65; i<=90; i++) printf("%c", i); printf("/");
                             for(i=97; i<=122; i++) printf("%c", i)}')'/' data
```